# Cors Error after deploying Springboot Application to AWS

Tags: reactjs, spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, cors

I'm working on a SpringBoot and React FullStack Application, I first encountered Cors Error while running on localhost, i fixed the error by configuring Cors to allow all methods and origins. That fixed the issue on localhost but after deploying my Application on AWS, the Cors Error returned and my frontend couldn’t fetch data from the server.

Below is my Config Class:

```
public class WebMvcConfig  implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Value("#{'${cors.allowed-origins}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> allowedOrigins;

    @Value("#{'${cors.allowed-methods}'.split(',')}")
    private List<String> allowedMethods;

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry){
        final CorsRegistration corsRegistration = registry.addMapping("/api/**");
        allowedOrigins.forEach(corsRegistration::allowedOrigins);
        allowedMethods.forEach(corsRegistration::allowedMethods);
    }
}
```

I have configured my the server to accept requests from all origins and methods.

Below is the app running on localhost
[image: app running on localhost]

And here's the app after deploying to AWS
[image: app running on AWS]

I've tried all i could to fix this but to no avail. Please help.

Comment: It would be interesting to see, what the value of `cors.allowed-origins` is.

Comment: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8Mpu.png) I declared the values in application.yml file. I've uploaded the image in that link

Comment: In addition, cors.allowed-origins is set to "*" so it's weird getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see the request from ReactJs but it would seem that you are missing the protocol (or it is a wrong protocol) in your call. Do you have the `http://` in front of the URL?